# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installation stucks

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installation stucks at Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795 In Process Monitor it shows message result No such file Path %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights\vstelAIF-312cbd79-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70*.trn I tried to put empty file a.trn in folder vstelAIF-312cbd79-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70 and after that it says error Invalid name parameter. I first tried to install Visual Studio 2017 beside Visual Studio 2015 then I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and install Visual Studio 2017 and same problem happens.I tried to skip Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795 but then in stucks at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime with same message.

Comment: Is your installation running from a local download folder that was created with -layout? If yes, make sure you imported the files in the certificates directory. 

In any case, make sure that if an AntiVirus program runs on your computer you disable it for the duration of the installation - colleague and I had trouble there that resulted in what you describe. There should also be a log file in `%APPDATA%\..\Local\Temp` should start with `dd_`. Take a look at that and the last log message regarding Win10SDK or/and JustInTime.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar hangs with various Visual Studio operations (including installation) in the past.

The solution has been to create an empty file in the directory (or directories) it's looking for with a .trn extension. For whatever reason this satisfies it and it's able to progress past this point.