# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 "Server Busy" every time I open a dialog. Devenv.exe is faulting with textservice.dll

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019, busy-waiting, naturallyspeaking

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 shows a "Server Busy" dialog every time I open a dialog.

A Procmon search for devenv.exe finds at least 100 NO SUCH FILE entries for the following file:

```
C:\Users\jlavallet\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights\vstelf144292e-e3b2-4011-ac90-20e5c03fbce5\*.trn
FileInformationClass:   FileBothDirectoryInformation
Filter: *.trn
```

[image: Procman results]

I performed the search because I was following @Blaise's  advice to the OP of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026817/969431

So now that I have found the offending file, what advice can you give me for resolving this issue?

UPDATE:

So I googled the path and filename and found this SO question: [Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installation stucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743383/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-installation-stucks).

I tried the solution suggested by @Techrocket9, placing an empty TRN file in the folder.

[image: Folder now containing Dummy.trn]

I then started up Visual Studio again and tried to edit the Publish settings for a solution (this invokes a modal dialog) and as always, about five seconds later, I get that same "Server Busy" dialog:

[image: Server Busy dialog]

I went back to Procmon and the NO SUCH FILE problem was gone but I decided to filter the remaining devenv.exe entries down to just those that were not SUCCESS or NO MORE FILES (this seemed innocuous). Here's what I have left:

[image: Remaining Procman entries]

Does anyone out there know what might be causing my Server Busy problem based on this information?

UPDATE 2

After multiple tries at reinstalling and working the issue through Microsoft here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/com-returned-an-unexpected-error-code-details-are/1422343?from=email&viewtype=all, I cleared my Event Viewer Application Logs and isolated everything. The result was that I found this error message. Devenv.exe appears to be conflicting with my voice recognition software Nuance Dragon NaturallySpeaking 15. Since this is an accessibility issue, is there any chance that Microsoft will do something about this? What can I do?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          5/14/2021 3:39:39 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DEVELOPMENT9.CC.Local
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.9.31205.134, time stamp: 0x606b75b3
Faulting module name: textservice.dll, version: 15.61.200.14, time stamp: 0x5fb72e0e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00006644
Faulting process id: 0x3a40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d74900f8dd3c3e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking15\Program\textservice.dll
Report Id: fa11cc8c-975c-42b8-af6a-3cd00b12dc7a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:

  
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-14T20:39:39.6605762Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7267273707</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DEVELOPMENT9.CC.Local</Computer>
    <Security />
  
  
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>16.9.31205.134</Data>
    <Data>606b75b3</Data>
    <Data>textservice.dll</Data>
    <Data>15.61.200.14</Data>
    <Data>5fb72e0e</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00006644</Data>
    <Data>3a40</Data>
    <Data>01d74900f8dd3c3e</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking15\Program\textservice.dll</Data>
    <Data>fa11cc8c-975c-42b8-af6a-3cd00b12dc7a</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
```

UPDATE 3:

So it turns out that the issue is some kind of conflict between Visual Studio 2019 and Nuance Dragon Professional Group 15. I am now working the problem with Microsoft and Nuance.  If this has affected anyone besides me, you can follow the continued progress here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-server-busy-every-tim/1416496?from=email&viewtype=all.